# Hola, Quiero saber que variable puedo usar para sumar 2 o mas productos por un mismo precio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, app

Tengo dos opciones CANTIDAD y PRECIO, si pongo 5 en cantidad y en precio pongo 2$ quiero que me sume ese resultado en la opción TOTAL

hasta ahora tengo:

```js
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var cantidad = double.Parse(Cantidad.Text);
   var precio = double.Parse(Precio.Text);
}
```

Comment: sobre que estas trabajando aparte de c#?

Comment: una app basada en Xamarin

Answer (score 2):

Podrías simplemente crear otra variable, que sea double y le colocas el resultado

```
double total = cantidad  * precio;
```